# Rename estimate for the constant for coefplot

Tags: stata

I want to create in Stata a coefplot variable: however, in one of the models I want to show there is no value for the estimate which I report, but instead I want to report the constant.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
sysuse auto, clear
regress price weight
coefplot, drop(weight) rename(_cons = abcdef)
```

[image]